# Optimize the pandas code for large dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

**Input**

| id | name | genre | year | language | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ab123 | Interstellar | Sci-fi | 2020 | English | Hollywood |
| ab125 | hero | Action | 2020 | English | Hollywood |
| ab123 | Interstellar | Space | 2020 | English | Hollywood |

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "id": "ab123",
    "name": "Interstellar",
    "classifications": {
      "classification": [
        {
          "genre": "Sci-fi",
          "year": 2020
        },
        {
          "genre": "Space",
          "year": 2020
        }
      ]
    },
    "language": "English",
    "type": "Hollywood"
  },
  {
    "id": "ab125",
    "name": "Hero",
    "classifications": {
      "classification": [
        {
          "genre": "Action",
          "year": 2020
        },
        {
          "genre": "Fighthing",
          "year": 2020
        }
      ]
    },
    "language": "English",
    "type": "Hollywood"
  },
  {
    "id": "ab567",
    "name": "Love",
    "classifications": {
      "classification": [
        {
          "genre": "Dram",
          "year": 2022
        }
      ]
    },
    "language": "English",
    "type": "Hollywood"
  }
]
```

I am using pandas to get my desired output.

```
import pandas
import json

df = pandas.read_excel('C:/Users/pika/Desktop/sample.xlsx', sheet_name='Movie')

# Do a group by and name the newly created column
final = df.groupby(['id', 'name', 'language', 'type']).apply(lambda x: {"classification":x[['genre','year']].to_dict('records')}).reset_index(name="classifications").to_dict(orient="records")

print(json.dumps(final, indent=2))
```

My question:

1. Is there any room for improvement in my current pandas code? Because i have plans to apply the same code to a large dataset of data which has around 50 columns in it.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to order the columns in the JSON output? Note that `final` is not a dataframe, it's a dictionary.

Comment: @Nick Yes, you are right. I had a misbelief that JSON Schema validates the order of attributes in JSON. But after your question, and read the JSON Schema docs and found that order does not matter. Thanks

Comment: It seems reasonable although I'm not sure why you need the second level of dict ('classifications' and 'classification')

Comment: It won't make much sense in the above payload but in the real dataset we are doing some of kind of analysis based on ('classifications' and 'classification')